# how to import es6 modules in karma

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I'm trying to do some testing with karma, mocha and chai. I'm confused how to import es6 module correctly in karma. I am already use `karma-babel-preprocessor`. Could anyone help me, thanks a lot!

Here is the error when run `npm test`
[image: karma error report]

Here is my karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
    files: ['src/index.js', 'test/test_karma.js'],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {
      'src/index.js': ['babel'],
      'test/test_karma.js': ['babel]
    },
    babelPreprocessor: {
      options: {
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
      }
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless', 'Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Here is my index.js

```
const sayHello = () => {
  return 'hello karma'
}
export { sayHello }
```

Here is my test_karma.js

```
import {sayHello} from '../src/index';
import chai from 'chai';

describe('test', () => {
  it('test', () => {
    chai.assert(sayHello() === 'hello', 'say hello')
  })
})
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this problem? I am having it too... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63836516/test-lit-element-webcomponent-with-karma