# Test lit-element webcomponent with Karma

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, web-component, lit-element, web-component-tester

I am trying to create a blank project, like a template, using lit-html. I wanted to also add some testing capabilities, so i have been trying to get it to work with Karma.

I can run a normal test, like an addition, without any errors, so i think Karma itself is running ok. but i can't run any test involving the webcomponent. **I can't import the webcomponent!**

i am exporting the webcomponent with:
`export default class MyComponent ...`

and then on the test file i am importing it with:
`import MyComponent from 'pathToComponent/MyComponent'`

When i run the test i get:

```
Error loading test file: /test/example.test.js
TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:9876/base/test/example.test.js
```

I have it on a github repo here: https://github.com/boguz/rollup-lit-redux, so you can take a better look if you need to see what other packages i have installed.

Any help is very appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is due to a module referenced by `/test/example.test.js` - the error message is a little deceptive...

> Failed to fetch *dynamically* imported module

The clue is that you didn't *dynamically* import (that's when you use `const module = await import('path')` and you'd get an exception on that line if it failed) - you statically imported. That error message is not because it couldn't find `http://localhost:9876/base/test/example.test.js`, it's that it couldn't find a nested reference in that file.

At a guess `example.test.js` contains an `import` with a relative path that isn't served:

```
import * as testFramework from './testFramework';

export default class MyComponent...
```

That works in TypeScript and linting tools because it can resolve `./testFramework` to `./testFramework.d.ts`, `./node_modules/@types/testFramework.d.ts` or whatever type lookup you're using.

However, in the browser it doesn't know you actually want `./testFramework.js` or `./testFramework/index.js`, it requests `./testFramework` directly, gets a 404, and then gives you that error for the calling component.

In short:

- If you *statically* import (i.e. with `import * from ...`)
- But you get

> Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: filename.js

- The error is actually with another static `import` in `filename.js`, not getting `filename.js` itself.

The network tab will point you at which dependency is the problem, as it will be a 404, and the fix is either resolve these imports with your build tools, or put the full relative path to the .js file in your source.